# No route matches [GET] "/admin/signout"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise gem to build the admin/user authentication to my web app.

I'm getting this error: No route matches [GET] "/admin/signout", when I click in the 'sign out' link.

my html slim code: `= link_to destroy_admin_session_path, method: :delete`

Ran 'rake routes', and the application has destroy_admin_session

And I saw in Google Chrome's inspect element that the link has 'data-method=delete'.

My sessions controller:

```
# encoding: utf-8
class Admin::Devise::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  layout 'login'

  def after_sign_in_path_for(admin)
    admin_admins_path
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    new_admin_session_path
  end

end
```

But I'm getting a [GET] error. What could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if jquery and jquery_ujs are required in your application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

and make sure you load the application.js in your layout file:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

Since you can't actually make a link use the HTTP DELETE method, Rails is doing some magic with the link if you put the `method: :delete` to the helper.

That's why you need the javascript.

Comment: Thanks! That worked!

But if I don't want to use jquery and jquery_ujs.. What do I need to do with the application? For example: I want to use angular instead of Jquery..

Comment: I don't see how Angular is an alternative for jQuery. They are two totally different packages. You can use Angular beside jQuery.

Comment: The company I work, we use Angular instead of Jquery for all interactivity in the websites. 

When I remove jquery or jquery_ujs, the remove method doesn't work. But I don't want to use Jquery

Comment: Ok, some googling took me to https://github.com/tomchentw/angular-ujs. Never used it, but looks like something you can work with